# String in superscript is coming as ? in HTML page

Tags: java, html, string, unicode, ascii

I am trying to process the data coming from Eventhub (messages pushed through MQTTBox) in Java. All data is fine, except superscript characters in String data. Characters in superscript are coming as ? (or) � .
Tried using StandardCharsets.US_ASCII and StandardCharsets.UTF_8. How to resolve this issue. Is there anything that I am missing here.

Input :: "mL/b/m2"   (2 in superscript of m.. Unable to paste it here)
Output :: "mL/b/m?"

Comment: Start by learning what � [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)).

Comment: “Tried using StandardCharsets.US_ASCII and StandardCharsets.UTF_8.”  Edit your question and show us where and how you used those charsets.